# How to select fields of a contained association?

Tags: cakephp, select, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

I would like to execute the following query where I'd like to read only the necessary fields from associated.
I used a dot notation in `select()` below to better explain what I want.
Basically the `select()` seems to concern `Users` only. Is it possible to specify the fields of `Sites`?

```
$orders = $this->Orders->find()
    ->contain([
        'Sites.Users'=> function ($q) {
            return $q
                ->select([
                    'Sites.id',
                    'Sites.user_id',
                    'Users.id',
                    'Users.name',
                    'Users.owner_id',
                    'Users.firstname',
                    'Users.lastname'
                ])
                ->autoFields(false);
        },
    ])
    ->first();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to configure the containments individually, selecting fields for other containments won't work.

To be exact, you cannot select fields for a containment from anywhere else than the corresponding containment configuration, with the only exception of `belongsTo/hasOne` associations that are using the join strategy, fields for them can be selected in the `select()` call of the immediate "parent" query, as these associations are going to be retrieved via a join in that query.

If for example `Sites` would be a `belongsTo` association, then you could select the fields for it via the `select()` call on `Orders`. If `Users` would be a `belongsTo`, but `Sites` a `hasMany`, then you could use the `select()` call for `Sites` to select fields for `Users`.

That being said, in your case you either use the `queryBuilder` option to define callbacks in a nested array structure

```
contain([
    'Sites' => [
        'queryBuilder' => function ($q) {
            return $q
                ->select([
                    'Sites.id',
                    'Sites.user_id'
                ]);
        },
        'Users' => function ($q) {
            return $q
                ->select([
                    'Users.id',
                    'Users.name',
                    'Users.owner_id',
                    'Users.firstname',
                    'Users.lastname'
                ]);
        }
    ]
])
```

or, if you don't actually need the query builder, use the `fields` option

```
contain([
    'Sites' => [
        'fields' => [
            'Sites.id',
            'Sites.user_id'
        ],
        'Users' => [
            'fields' => [
                'Users.id',
                'Users.name',
                'Users.owner_id',
                'Users.firstname',
                'Users.lastname'
            ]
        ]
    ]
])
```

See also

- **[Cookbok > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Passing Conditions to Contain](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#passing-conditions-to-contain)**
- **[API > \Cake\ORM\QueryBuilder::contain()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.ORM.Query.html#_contain)**