# How to get only selected fields from rightJoin() and contain() in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.2

cakephp 3.2.3x

I am trying to show custom fields from right join which is contained (left joined) with an other table and it is not working. How ever contain custom fields is working.

**Note 1:** When I get rid of `contain()` my ORM works as I am expecting.

```
$properties = $this->find() 
            ->select([
                'Property.id', 'Property.company_id', 'Property.address1', 'Property.postcode', 
                'Tenancies.property_id', 'Tenancies.start_date', 'Tenancies.end_date', 'Tenancies.deposit_total',
            ])
            ->rightJoin(['Tenancies' => 'tenancy'],[
                'Tenancies.property_id = Property.id',
                'Tenancies.active = 1'
            ])
            ->contain([
                'Tenancies.Tenants' => function($q) {
                    return $q
                        ->select([
                            'Tenants.id', 'Tenants.stage', 'Tenants.tenancy_id', 'Tenants.holding_fee',
                        ])
                        ->where([
                            'active = 1',
                        ]);
                    }
            ])
            ->where(['Property.active = 1', $conditions]);
```

**Note 2:** Generated sql is correct but it is not applying to the query.

> 'SELECT `Property`.`id` AS `Property__id`, `Property`.`company_id` AS
>   `Property__company_id`, `Property`.`address1` AS `Property__address1`,
>   `Property`.`postcode` AS `Property__postcode`,
>   `Tenancies`.`property_id` AS `Tenancies__property_id`,
>   `Tenancies`.`start_date` AS `Tenancies__start_date`,
>   `Tenancies`.`end_date` AS `Tenancies__end_date`,
>   `Tenancies`.`deposit_total` AS `Tenancies__deposit_total` FROM
>   `property` `Property` RIGHT JOIN `tenancy` `Tenancies` ON
>   (Tenancies.property_id = Property.id AND Tenancies.active = 1) WHERE
>   (Property.active = 1 AND `Property`.`company_id` = :c0)'

The query should show me only 3 fields of 'Tenancies' but it retrieves all the `Tenancies` fields.

```
(int) 0 => [
    'id' => (int) 102,
    'company_id' => (int) 3,
    'address1' => 'Grace Dieu Court',
    'postcode' => 'LE11 4QH',
    'tenancies' => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'id' => (int) 16,
            'property_id' => (int) 102,
            'landlord_id' => (int) 65,
            'agent_id' => (int) 7,
            'company_id' => (int) 3,
            'bedroom' => (int) -1,
            'created' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {
                'time' => '2015-05-08T09:30:41+00:00',
                'timezone' => 'UTC',
                'fixedNowTime' => false             
            },
            'active' => true,
             ...
             ...  ## } The rest of all fileds
            'tenants' => [
                (int) 0 => [
                    'id' => (int) 16,
                    'stage' => (int) 7,
                    'tenancy_id' => (int) 16,
                    'holding_fee' => (float) 50
                ],
                (int) 1 => [
                    'id' => (int) 17,
                    'stage' => (int) 7,
                    'tenancy_id' => (int) 16,
                    'holding_fee' => (float) 50
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
],
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CakePHP3: select() and dot notation associated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35706399/cakephp3-select-and-dot-notation-associated)

Comment: @ndm The ORM retrieves all the rightJoin() or innerJoinWith() fields when I use the contain()

Comment: It's not a matter of `rightJoin/innerJoinWith` usage, you're simply not defining the fields to select (properly). For `hasMany/belongsToMany` associations, you cannot select fields for a containment from anywhere else than the corresponding containment configuration. See the possible duplicate for an example of how define the fields.